# Can't get org.jetbrains.intellij plugin in Gradle build

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to include "org.jetbrains.intellij" plugin to my project for using JetBrains annotation `@NotNull` in JUnit tests while testing project with Gradle. But Gradle try to download this plugin from `cache-redirector.jetbrains.com`.

Company, where I try to do that, uses inner Artifactory for keeping dependencies. And I've already set my `settings.gradle.kts` pluginManagement for using Artifactory. Other plugins successfully downloaded and installed except JetBrains one.

What and where should I modify to force Gradle download plugin from company's Artifactory, not from `cache-redirector.jetbrains.com`?

Comment: org.jetbrains.intellij is a plugin for building IntelliJ IDEA plugins. If you aren't building a plugin, you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @NotNull annotation doesn't work in gradle build process because gradle ignore it, but if you include plugin org.jetbrains.intellij, gradle will understand jetbrains annotations in build process.